# matplotlib.pyplot.subplots() - how to set the name of the figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I create a single plot using the figure()-function of PyPlot, I can set the name of the appearing window using a string as argument:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
figure = plt.figure('MyName')
```

The function plt.subplots() doesn´t accept strings as first argument. For example:

```
plt.subplots(2,2)  # for creating a window with 4 subplots
```

So how can I set the name of the figure?

Answer (score 25):

Taken from [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#...

# Just a figure and one subplot
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_title('Simple plot')
```

And, to change the title of the Window:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
fig = plt.figure() 
fig.canvas.manager.set_window_title('My Window Title') 
plt.show()
```

If you're using a Matplotlib version < 3.4, use: `fig.canvas.set_window_title('My Windows Title')`

[Reference to deprecation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.4.0.html#backend-deprecations) (kudos to KaiserKatze).

Comment: set_title('string') only sets the title of the plot, not the name of the window that is showing up, when you run the code. The window keeps called "Figure 1".

Comment: @MoTSCHIGGE: The last sentence of the OP's question states: _So how can I set the name of the figure?_ However, I've addressed your concerns - as I possibly misread it wrong. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 21):

`plt.subplots()` passes additional keyword arguments to `plt.figure`. Therefore, the `num` keyword will do what you want.

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, num='MyName')
```

You can also set `figsize` and `dpi` etc. in this way too (see `plt.figure` [docs](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure)).

Comment: I hunted hi and low for this answer and finally found it here!  Thanks for this.  Matplotlib's documentation is just a hot mess.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,2, num = PlotName)
```

where `PlotName` is a string and thus you can generate a window name upon instantiation