# assigning name to matplotlib subplot figure that can be used to make figure current

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

My question is very similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387365/matplotlib-pyplot-subplots-how-to-set-the-name-of-the-figure), but I'd like to be able to make the named figure current again, which the solution to the other question didn't address. Here's an attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
f, ax = plt.subplots()
f.canvas.set_window_title('My Window Title') 

# make another figure, which will become current
plt.figure()

# attempts to make previous figure current, but instead creates third figure
plt.figure('My Window Title')
```

Is there a way to assign a name to a figure that's created using subplots() that can be referred to later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep using [`plt.subplots()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots), you can give the figure its name using keyword arguments. Any kwargs not used by `subplots` are passed on to `plt.figure`, so in this case we want to set the `num` option (that's what you are setting to `'My Window Title'` in your example:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(num='My Window Title')
```

Comment: This does not work, but ```f, ax = plt.subplots(num='My Window Title')``` does work.

Comment: Ah yes thanks; I misread the docs. I've edited my answer with your correction

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. The answer is to separate out the `f,ax=plt.subplots()` line and use the add_subplot command:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
f = plt.figure('My Window Title')
ax = f.add_subplot(1,2,1)
# ...

# make another figure, which will become current
plt.figure()

# make previous figure current
plt.figure('My Window Title')
```